# ActiveRecord-JDBC is for use with JRuby only problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I'm running ruby script/server from the command line and getting

```
ActiveRecord-JDBC is for use with JRuby only
```

it then suggests gem `install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter`

but when I try this it says that

```
(no such file to load -- java) (RuntimeError)
```

I've tried a fresh install of Rails and reinstalling the gems, but still not joy. Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to use JDBC but not jruby?

Comment: forgive my naivety, I just started with Rails and was using Netbeans as an IDE, but ran into problems, so thought I'd switch back to using the command line.

Comment: so I guess I'm not trying to use jruby

Answer (score 1):

Probably you generate your project using the default Netbeans settings which uses JRuby, so your project was created for JRuby and when you try to run it using mongrel you got that error.

Try creating a new project using ruby in Netbeans.